# keep getting 404 error with axios error although i made router with express router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, http-status-code-404

I'm keep getting 404 error with axios error even though i made router.

this is my frontend with axios

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function RecruitStatus() {
  const [Reviewers, setReviewers] = useState([])

  const getReviewers = () => {
    axios.get('/getprojectRequests')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success) {
                  setReviewers(response.data.reviewers)
            } else {
                alert('Failed to fetch product datas')
            }
        })
      }

  useEffect(() => {
    
    getReviewers()
  }, [])
```

this is my backend with express router

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { projectRequests } = require("../models/projectRequests");


router.get("/getprojectRequests", (req, res) => {
    projectRequests
        .find()
        .exec((err, reviewers) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err })
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, reviewers})
        })
});
```

Comment: post full code including app.js file where your routes will be used

Comment: Please paste full code snippets with a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think while making the request in the frontend you have to write the entire link like this
`axios.get('http://localhost:3000/getprojectRequests')`

Or whatever port you are running on.